# How to handle compile errors in webpack-dev-server with nodejs

Tags: error-handling, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I use `webpack` in `nodejs`, it can catch every compile error, the watching callback will be called every build end.

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

const compiler = webpack({
  // Configuration Object
});

const watching = compiler.watch({
  /* watchOptions */
}, (err, stats) => {
  // Print watch/build result here...
  console.log(stats);
});
```

But when I use `webpack-dev-server`, the listen callback only called once when the server started, its there any way to catch every compile error when use `webpack-dev-server` in `nodejs`?

```
const compiler = Webpack(webpackConfig);
const server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
  stats: {
    colors: true
  }
});

server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1', () => {
  // only called once
  console.log('bla');
});
```

Comment: I believe the stats property in the webpack-dev-server config might facilitate what you are trying to do. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/ Take a look at these options.

Answer (score 1):

finally solved this problem with plugin

```
compiler.plugin('done',callback)
```

this callback will be called every build done.